# Dropdown in Angular6 with Bootstrap 4.1.3 does not work

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, dropdown

trying to implement a dropdown in an angular-app with bootstrap, I am having problems with the layout of the dropdown. The dropdown opens to the left of the button and not as a real dropdown to the bottom. Furthermore the complete navbar gets a new height.

[image]

My HTML looks like following:

**HTML**

```
    <div class="btn-group" >
      <button
        type="button class="
        btn btn-success dropdown-toggle"
        data-toggle="dropdown"
        aria-haspopup="false" 
        aria-expanded="false" 
        (click)="panelExpanded = !panelExpanded">Login
      </button>
      <div  *ngIf="panelExpanded" >
        <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/signin">Anmelden</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/signup">Registrieren</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

`panelExpanded` is just a boolean in the .ts-file.

I tried the two suggested solutions and both did not work so far:

1. adding `class="dropdown-menu"`
2. installing bootstrap (see following)

After adding following import-statement to the angular.json, it still does not work:

`"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",`

Additionally I installed ng-bootstrap

`npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`

and bootstrap

`npm i --save bootstrap`

I got the following messages though:

`bootstrap@4.1.3 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1`

`bootstrap@4.1.3 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.14.3`

Do I have to install those two packages, as well?

I tried to include the ng-bootstrap-script within angular.json, as well, still without success

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/fesm5/ng-bootstrap.js",
]
```

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: Do yourself a favor, and use ng-bootstrap. It has a battle-tested dropdown already.

Comment: you do not require jquery.js, tether.js or bootstrap.js when using ng-bootstrap. The ng-bottstrap library is to replace those scripts with native Angular 2 code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution:-

Add: - `class="dropdown-menu"`

Link:- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stqy1h?file=src/app/app.component.html

```
<div class="btn-group" >
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown" 
      aria-haspopup="false" 
        aria-expanded="false" 
        (click)="panelExpanded = !panelExpanded">
        Login
      </button>
      <div   class="dropdown-menu" *ngIf="panelExpanded" >
        <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/signin">Anmelden</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/signup">Registrieren</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

As suggested above by Nizet, you can use @ng-bootstrap too.

For this:-

```
1) npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
2) npm i --save bootstrap
```

### angular.json:-

```
"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.css"
```

or:-

```
1) npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

2) import bootstrap style sheet file, into root style.css as below:

@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

For using ng-bootstrap,you do not require jquery.js, tether.js or bootstrap.js when using ng-bootstrap. The ng-bottstrap library is to replace those scripts with native Angular 2+ code.

kindly visit https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home

Comment: Accept it as answer, if it helps you. Don'..t edit your question instead ask a new question.

Comment: Perhaps, you have not checked Stackblitz. It's working perfectly. Don't edit questions based on suggestions, instead raise a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved.

That would be the **HTML** for the header.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light mb-5 fixed-top">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>
        <div class="navbar-expand mr-auto">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/dashboard">Main Page</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/about">About</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-expand ml-auto">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Login</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/signin">My Profile</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/signup">Register</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

and in the `index.html` I've added those scripts.

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Using Jquery is not suggested with angular 2+. Angular2+ is to replace these scripts. Hence, don't mix Jquery with angular 2 or angular 2+

Comment: but when I delete the script the dropdown does not work anymore, so I will just post a new question

Comment: You have asked about bootstrap-dropdown, later edited question based on suggestions. Bootstrap-dropdown issue is resolved. You don't need require .js for dropdown. In angular2+ avoid using jquery etc:-

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap - 4.4.1, 
Angular-cli: 7.3.9

Javascript files in, npm modules need to sent js files to the client, so you will need to tell the meteor that you want it.

The easiest way is to import the js bundle in your client entry point:

`import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle';` line into '**polyfills.ts**' file